# Using R to read a GSE table

Tags: r, text, bioinformatics

I downloaded supplementary files by running this command in R,

```
filePaths = getGEOSuppFiles("GSE60341")
```

This created two files,

1. `GSE60341_nanostring_processed_data.txt`; and
2. `GSE60341_RAW`

How can I make R read `GSE60341_nanostring_processed_data.txt` as a meaningful data frame?

Comment: well, have you tried `read.table`?

Comment: Generally, the geoQuery package allows you to get both the raw values from the array/expression set and the processed data (meaning processed however the GEO accession says it was processed). You can just read the processed values in like @cel says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read.table` is probably the best option and will even read in a *.gz file:

```
temp <- read.table("GSE60341/GSE60341_nanostring_processed_data.txt.gz")
> dim(temp)
[1]  251 1950
```

There is a great GEOquery tutorial [here](https://genomicsclass.github.io/book/pages/GEOquery.html)

Comment: Upvoted because you almost got 3k. Cheap one, though :)